# Пытаюсь заставить GCC генерировать инструкцию при ситуации

Tags: c, gcc

Необходимо уменьшить количество переходов(branch) при заданной ситуации, существует тест называемый median содержащий в том числе данный код:

```
      void median( int n, int input[], int results[] )
    {
      int A, B, C, i;

      // Zero the ends
      results[0]   = 0;
      results[n-1] = 0;

      // Do the filter
      for ( i = 1; i < (n-1); i++ ) {

        A = input[i-1];
        B = input[i];
        C = input[i+1];

        if ( A < B ) {
          if ( B < C )
            results[i] = B;
          else if ( C < A )
            results[i] = A;
          else
            results[i] = C;
        }

        else {
          if ( A < C )
            results[i] = A;
          else if ( C < B )
            results[i] = B;
          else
            results[i] = C;
        }

      }

    }
```

Я составил следующий паттерн в файле *.md - машинных описаний:

```
    ;;Iterator for hardware minmax, u for unsigned
(define_code_iterator any_maxmin [smax smin umax umin])

(define_code_attr maxmin [(smax "max") (smin "min")
              (umax "maxu") (umin "minu")])             


(define_insn "<code><GPR:mode>3"
  [(set (match_operand:GPR           0 "register_operand" "=r")
    (any_maxmin:GPR (match_operand:GPR 1 "register_operand" " r")
          (match_operand:GPR 2 "register_operand" " r")))]
  ""
  "<maxmin>\t%0,%1,%2"
  [(set_attr "type" "move")
   (set_attr "mode" "<MODE>")])
```

Он работает в простых случаях, например без конструкции FOR-THEN:

```
    if ( A < B ) {
              if ( B < C )
                results[i] = B;
              else if ( C < A )
                results[i] = A;
              else
                results[i] = C;
            }

            else {
              if ( A < C )
                results[i] = A;
              else if ( C < B )
                results[i] = B;
              else
                results[i] = C;
            }
```

GCC генерирует инструкцию:

```
     ....
    max a0,a0,a1    # 9 smaxdi3 [length = 4]
    sd  a0,0(a3)   # 75 *movdi_internal/4   [length = 4]
    ret # 21    simple_return   [length = 4]
     ....
     ....
```

В случае с результирующим массивом results[] типа long также все работает:

```
     void median( int n, int input[], long results[] )
     ....
     ....
     else {
          if ( A < C )
            results[i] = A;
          else if ( C < B )
            results[i] = B;
          else
            results[i] = C;
        }
     ....
     ....
```

GCC генерирует:

```
     ....
    max a0,a1,a2    # 11    *smaxdi3    [length = 4]
    sd  a0,8(a2)    # 13    *movdi_64bit/4  [length = 4]
    ret # 28    simple_return   [length = 4]
     ....
     ....
```

В случае оригинального кода GCC игнорирует конструкцию noce_try_minmax прохода *.243r.ce1, c помощью которой он обычно разрешает ситуацию упрощения условного исполнения(conditional execution), вместо этого он принимает решение использовать IF-CASE-2 конструкции find_if_case_2, как описано в ifcvt.c

```
try_optimize_cfg iteration 1

;; 2 loops found
;;
;; Loop 0
;;  header 0, latch 1
;;  depth 0, outer -1
;;  nodes: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
;;
;; Loop 1
;;  header 15, latch 14
;;  depth 1, outer 0
;;  nodes: 15 14 7 10 12 13 5 8 6 4 3 11 9
;; 2 succs { 15 }
;; 3 succs { 4 9 }
;; 4 succs { 5 6 }
;; 5 succs { 14 }
;; 6 succs { 7 8 }
;; 7 succs { 14 }
;; 8 succs { 14 }
;; 9 succs { 10 11 }
;; 10 succs { 14 }
;; 11 succs { 12 13 }
;; 12 succs { 14 }
;; 13 succs { 14 }
;; 14 succs { 15 }
;; 15 succs { 3 16 }
;; 16 succs { 1 }
starting the processing of deferred insns
ending the processing of deferred insns
df_analyze called

IF-THEN-ELSE-JOIN block found, pass 1, test 6, then 7, else 8, join 14

IF-CASE-2 found, start 6, else 8

IF-THEN-ELSE-JOIN block found, pass 1, test 11, then 12, else 13, join 14

IF-CASE-2 found, start 11, else 13


========== no more changes

4 possible IF blocks searched.
0 IF blocks converted.
0 true changes made.




try_optimize_cfg iteration 1

starting the processing of deferred insns
ending the processing of deferred insns
```

Правка 1:
Инструкция генерится на шаге *.c.243r.ce1 - первый проход CE1( Conditional Execution). На этом проходе используется файл "обработки" ifcvt.с, в котором описываются случаи упрощения условных переходов, такие как minmax, abs итд. Копание в исходниках установило, что почти все эти условия отклоняются в случае использования subreg в RTL. Выражения subreg же, используются для ссылки на регистр в машинном режиме, отличном от его естественного режима, или для ссылки на один регистр из нескольких частей регистра, который фактически ссылается на несколько регистров, а это как раз мой случай, так как массив является типом INT, в то время как машина имеет 64бит REG по причине разрядности - RV64GC. Далее отслеживание шагов выявило, что начиная с шага 229 - первого шага RTL, "SSA tree form / CFG -> optimization" вставляет эти SUBREG сразу же, при переходе из GIMPLE в RTL, что в общем то логично. Задача меняется на анализ механизма генерации REG/SUBREG и соответствующей оптимизации.

Найдется ли тот, кто так глубоко в дебри GCC залезал?
Буду благодарен любой помощи, и нет, оптимизировать бенчмарк median не выход!

Comment: Если этот участок кода так критичен, может быть стоит его самим написать на ассемблере? Потому что, даже если Вы сейчас добьетесь нужного Вам результата генерации кода, вовсе не факт, что в следующей версии GCC кодогенератор будет работать так же.

Comment: Общая цель - создание конкретного тулчейна под конкретное железо, и если вы не заметили, НОВЫХ инструкций которые реализованы в железе, но не реализованы в GCC. Тулчейн будет иметь конечную версию, и будет поддерживаться своими силами.

Comment: Я не копался конкретно в gcc, но мне кажется что Вы пытаетесь сделать нетривиальное преобразование только через кодогенерацию. Подозреваю что в дальнейшем будет ещё не один частный случай когда простое правило не сработает. Возможно, имеет смысл написать отдельный проход, распознающий нужный шаблон и сворачивающий его во что-то вроде __builtin_minmax, а потом раскрывать builtin в инструкцию

Comment: В контексте вопроса ваш комментарий, как мне кажется, не имеет смысла. Паттерн уже написан, уже эмитится, но не в случаях, как выяснилось, использования SUBREG, позже дополню вопрос.